# how to fix .exe file , which is created using cx_freeze by converting .py to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, executable, cx-freeze

I have converted one .py file to .exe. The exe file created by this, is not working , it is closing automatically. In that application, I am supposed to take take two inputs. But screen is not staying.

I am using python 3.6 version. I have used cx_freeze library for this. 
I have mentioned the code below which I used to create .exe for setup.py

Setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name = "html_guid_compare",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Comparing two htm files for guid difference",
    executables = [Executable(r"htm_guid_compare2.py")]
)
```

Input code:

```
path1 = input("Enter the First folder path:")
path2 = input("Enter the second folder path:")
```

when clicked on .exe file. It is not showing the screen, the screen is terminated.

Comment: Does the screen not show at all? Or does it disappear once you have entered both inputs? Could you also please post a full [example] of your application?

Comment: It does not show the screen at all. I am just getting  a blink of it. Is there any way to check what is going on while starting of application?? @jpeg